# Forcing to redirect https to http in Apache 2.4

Tags: https, redirect, http, apache2

I am trying the following. I have a domain where I publish. This publication is only by http, but I need all requests by https to redirect me to http since I do not have ssl certificate installed and configured for this.

I have tried to add in the .htaccess file of the documentroot where I have the application the following lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond% {HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (. *) Http: //% {HTTP_HOST}% {REQUEST_URI} [R = 301, L]
```

But this does not make me that anything that enters through https redirects me to http. What would I be missing?

Best regards.

Edit:

OK.

Perfect now I think I understand it a little better. To redirect https to http, you must have an ssl certificate generated and stored on the apache server.

As a test, I created a self-signed certificate using the openssl tool

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa: 204 .....
```

I have generated it correctly.

The next step has been enabled the default-ssl.cnf site in which I add the paths of the ssl certificate data generated previously.

In this step, what action do I have to do to enable that redirection from https to http for my instance of wordpress for example.

Here is my default-ssl.conf file

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *: 443>
ServerName www.mydomain.org
ServerAdmin webmaster @ localhost
DocumentRoot / var / www / html/wordpress
<Directory />
FollowSymLinks options
AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory / var / www / html />
Options -Indexes + FollowSymLinks + MultiViews
Allow to cancel all
</Directory>
ErrorLog $ {APACHE_LOG_DIR} /error.log
Record Level Warning
CustomLog $ {APACHE_LOG_DIR} /ssl_access.log combined
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/sslcert/apache.key
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/sslcert/apache.crt
#SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/bundle.crt
BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
# MSIE 7 and later versions should be able to use keepalive
BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Regards

Comment: If you don't have an SSL certificate a redirect won't work. People would have to accept an invalid certificate before they get redirected. nobody will do that.

Comment: Apart from that your .htaccess files is full of syntax errors (spaces in the wrong place). you should get a 500 error with this.

Comment: Just get a free SSL certificate from e.g. letsencrypt.org instead. It'll save you a lot of hassle down the line.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot work without an ssl certificate.  Here's why:

When the browser connects to the server the security layer validates the connection (including the name(s) on the certificate with the name the browser is requesting) *before* the browser send the HTTP request (eg: GET / HTTP1/1).

The HTTP dialog is the same for both http and https, but the encryption is negotiated before it starts.

For HTTP 1.1 all requests should also havea Host: header specifiyng which host the request is for, Apache will calculate the full URI from the combination of the Host: header and the URI in the request.

If you can't start the HTTP conversation you can't get a request so you can't respond to it in any way.